# How do I terminate HandlerThreads?

Tags: android, multithreading

Following Googles examples for using a Service, I created a couple of threads like this.  I can't use IntentService, because I'm doing something that involves waiting for callbacks.

However, I don't know how to terminate a Thread started in this manner. As I understand it, Threads automatically terminate when the run() method returns.  However, this kind of thread doesn't have a run method.  My Threads are leaking--they stay alive after stopSelf().

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
    HandlerThread thread2 = new HandlerThread("CallbackHandling",
            android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread2.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mCallbackLooper = thread2.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new MyHandler(mServiceLooper);
    mCallbackHandler = new Handler(mCallbackLooper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
    // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    mMainThreadHandler=new Handler();
    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}

private final class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public MyHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        cycle();


        // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
        // the service in the middle of handling another job
        stopSelf(msg.arg1);
    }
}

protected void cycle() {
    ...
    mCallbackHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            goAskForSomeCallbacks();
        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(GIVE_UP_TIME);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        //The callback will interrupt this thread to stop it from waiting
        Log.d(TAG,"Got early callback, stop waiting.");
    }
    Thread.interrupted(); //clear the interrupt
    doStuff(); 

}
```

Comment: I cannot see why using callbacks would keep you from using an IntentService. I hope "waiting for callbacks" does not imply busy waiting here. If yes, then I'd suggest a redesign. If not then there's no reason to keep a separate HandlerThread an a per-expected-callback basis. Even if heavy postprocessing of data supplied by callbacks is involved, it might be wise to hava a queue for that etc. So it would be great to understand the architecture you have on your mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try calling the `quit` method on the corresponding Loopers.

Comment: @TenFour04 would you post the final solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can call quit method on your handler threads.

e.g.

```
thread.quit();
thread2.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following recommended approach:

but be careful before using it because it cancels all pending jobs

```
handler.quitSafely();
```

Answer (score -1):

Force closing the app does it but otherwise they just keep going on their own.